# Python- Update the value with 0 if element not found in JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a code where JSON file structure is read and Off_peak,Peak and Shoulder prices are extracted.
There are some JSON where all the elements are present whereas some of them has only Peak and Off_Peak but not shoulder.

```
try:
    for check in data[0]['planData']['contract'][0]['tariffPeriod'][0]['touBlock']:
        if "Off" in check['name']:
            Off_Peak = check['blockRate'][0]['unitPrice']
        elif "Peak" in check['name']:
            Peak = check['blockRate'][0]['unitPrice']
        elif "Shoulder" in check['name']:
            Shoulder = check['blockRate'][0]['unitPrice']
        
except:
    Off_Peak = ""
    Peak = ""
    Shoulder = ""
```

My code checks and updates the variable with all these elements even found or not. However, if only 2 elements are found then the one which is not found is not updated and I want to update it with 0.Example of API

```
API - https://api.energymadeeasy.gov.au/plans/dpids/AMA62448MBE1?postcode=4000
```

Example, there is a file which has Off_Peak and Peak but shoulder variable remains blank but I want to update it with 0 if not found. I tried  below code but it is not working.

```
for check in data[0]['planData']['contract'][0]['tariffPeriod'][0]['touBlock']:
    if "Off" in check['description']:
        Off_Peak = check['blockRate'][0]['unitPrice']
        print('Off_Peak',Off_Peak)
    elif "Peak" in check['description']:
        Peak = check['blockRate'][0]['unitPrice']
        print('Peak',Peak)
    elif "Shoulder" in check['description']:
        Shoulder = check['blockRate'][0]['unitPrice']
        print('Shoulder',Shoulder)
    elif Off_Peak==None:
        Off_Peak=0
    elif Peak==None:
        Peak=0
    elif Shoulder==None:
        Shoulder=0
```

Expected Output

```
Plan_ID Post_Code   Plan_Type   Plan_Name   Retailer_Name   Retailer_Code   Distributor_Name    State   Effective_Date  Solar_Rate  Discount_Type   Discount    Daily_Rate  CL1 CL2 Single_Rate Off_Peak    Peak    Shoulder
AMA62448MBE1    4000    TOU amaysim Post-paid Electricity - Business    amaysim Energy  AMA Energex QLD 1/07/2020   8           136.8               21.9648 23.328  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no need to complicate this, just set the initial values as 0 for all 3. If value is found set it again else it will remain 0 -

```
Off_Peak = 0
Peak = 0
Shoulder = 0
try:
    for check in data[0]['planData']['contract'][0]['tariffPeriod'][0]['touBlock']:
        if "Off" in check['name']:
            Off_Peak = check['blockRate'][0]['unitPrice']
        elif "Peak" in check['name']:
            Peak = check['blockRate'][0]['unitPrice']
        elif "Shoulder" in check['name']:
            Shoulder = check['blockRate'][0]['unitPrice']        
except:
    # No need to set it again, but not removing it
    Off_Peak = 0
    Peak = 0
    Shoulder = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Let me try. Quick question, can I add or in the if block. For example,
 if "Off" in check['name'] or "Off" in check['description']? Or I will have to use elif? I want to use OR function and sometimes Off is present either in 'name' or 'description'

Comment: Yes, you can add multiple conditions in `if` separated by `or` or `and`

Answer (score -1):

how about using a "ternary conditional" its one line that says if this else that.

i.e if found enter data into variable else enter 0

used like this

`test = True if 10+10 == 20 else False`

```
for check in data[0]['planData']['contract'][0]['tariffPeriod'][0]['touBlock']:
    Off_Peak = check['blockRate'][0]['unitPrice'] if "Off" in check['name'] else 0 
    Peak = check['blockRate'][0]['unitPrice'] if "Peak" in check['name'] else 0 
    Shoulder = check['blockRate'][0]['unitPrice'] if "Shoulder" in check['name'] else 0
```

EDIT:

I've just seen your API and haven't tested it at all!

Comment: This will not work as `else` condition will make all values 0 inside the loop

Comment: I tried, but it is not giving the desired result. For each name I am checking if it contains peak, off or shoulder in the text.
 0   0   0
21.9648   21.9648   21.9648